# matplotlib plt.xticks(rotation=90)を使うとlabelがprintされるのを、非表示にしたい。

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotでX軸を回転させたく、plt.xticks(rotaion=90)を使用しました。
plt.xticks()を使うことでjupyter notebook上でlabelがprintされます。
jupyter notebookで報告書を作成しているため、このprint文を表示させたくありません。
なにか方法ありますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

以下code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import japanize_matplotlib

data = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[4,5],[6,7]],columns=['x','y'])

data.plot()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

以下出力
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
(array([0.  , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  , 1.25, 1.5 , 1.75, 2.  ]),
 <a list of 9 Text xticklabel objects>)
```

を表示させたくありません。

Comment: `plt.xticks(rotation=90)` の直後で `plt.show()` を実行すれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`plt.xticks(rotation=90)`の後ろに`;`(セミコロン)を付けるか、最終行に`plt.show()`を追加しましょう。

Comment: セミコロン入れるやり方もあるんですね！とても参考になります。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

戻り値を（投げっぱなしでなく）たとえば変数に格納しましょう。

```py
_ = plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Comment: これ戻り値が表示されていたのですね。なるほど、ありがとうございます。すっきりしました。